# FET voltage-controlled resistor schematics

Tags: mosfet, sensor, resistance, control

I am trying to design and build a circuit that will accept a 1 to 5 VDC input and based on the voltage offer a 30 to 240 Ω resistance. I'd like the circuit to be linear.

ie R = 30 + 210 x (Vin-1)/4  ohms

The purpose of the circuit is to take the DC voltage from a water tank sensor and present the resistance to a network display panel that looks for a resistance to display the level of the tank.

I've found several schematics that include a FET with a 1-5 V input that controls resistance, but they appear to me to have AC inputs, not DC. I also have found some FETs listed as FET VCRs but they are either for audio applications or show a voltage on the gate to source FET leads, so I'm not sure if they would work or how to measure the resistance with a voltage on the leads.

Can anyone help with information or how I might go about getting this done?

Comment: I think a digital potentiometer is probably the best way to go about this, unless you can get to a schematic of the display circuitry to try to patch in your signal further down the line.

Comment: Incompatible vtc and "other action".

Answer (score 2):

> *The purpose of the circuit is to take accept the DC voltage from a
> water tank sensor and present the resistance to a network display
> panel that looks for a resistance to display the level of the tank.*

It may give the impression that it is looking for resistance but, in reality it's probably looking for voltage and, to assist in its quest, it will have a constant current generator producing maybe 1 mA across the measurement terminals.

So, what you need to do is "calibrate" your display with a few different values of resistance and measure what voltage appears across the terminals for each resistor value. This should likely tell you that it is in fact a voltage measuring device.

Then, all you need to do is buffer your 0 to 5 volt input to a voltage range suitable for the display.

On the other hand, it may be producing a fixed voltage and monitoring the current taken by the input resistor. Again this is easy to recreate but, the input signals need to be calibrated as per the earlier suggestion.

<sub>Trying to convert a voltage directly to a resistance value is quite complex if you want accuracy; it can be done but, explore the much easier options first.</sub>